# Use RxSwift Driver cause memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, driver, rx-swift

I write a demo about this leak.

```swift
import UIKit
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private let viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    private lazy var nameLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "idle"
        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.view.addSubview(nameLabel)
        nameLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 30)
        
        // not leak
        viewModel.name.asObservable().bind(to: nameLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        // leak
//        viewModel.name.asDriver().drive(onNext: { [weak self] (name) in
//            guard let weakSelf = self else { return }
//            weakSelf.nameLabel.text = name
//        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        // leak
//        viewModel.name.asDriver().drive(nameLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        viewModel.name.accept("act")
    }
}

class ViewModel {
    let name: BehaviorRelay<String> = BehaviorRelay(value: "")
}
```

In Xcode Instrument Leaks, it will report leaks when using driver. But change to "bindTo", it works fine and no leaks report.

I change "driver.driveTo" to driver.drive(onNext), and handle recycle problem, still report leaks.

I'm really confused about this. And I wish someone can tell me why this happened, how can I fix it, or avoid this kind of leaks in the future.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but the code you posted has no leaks in it. Even if I uncomment all the code you put in, everything is cleaned up appropriately when the view controller is dismissed. Maybe your leak has to do with something outside this class...

Comment: @DanielT. It's a clean project with only these code. Nothing else in it. I found leaks in my main project, and I make a new totally clean test project, with these code above. Run in iPhone X iOS 12.4, found leaks in Instruments Leaks. But The RxSwift's Resource Count looks fine. When push in this ViewController, then pop out, Resource Count didn't increase. But why my Instruments Leaks keep reporting leaks, It's really weard.

Comment: You cannot make a project with only the code above. There is no AppDelegate for example. There are no leaks in the code you posted. If you are seeing leaks, then they are coming from something outside this code.

Comment: @DanielT. Test Project has necessary code to run in iPhone. What I mean is create an empty project, which can run successfully in normal iOS device. Add these code to it, push this ViewController, I can find leaks in Instruments Leaks.

Comment: Show _all_ the code you added/changed in that base project. If there is a leak, it's in the code you aren't showing.